# xslt V1.0 - Simplest way to return multiple values from a subtemplate

Tags: templates, xslt, return, xslt-1.0

I'm looking for an elegant way to return multiple values from one subtemplate.

**why?** - I have a subtemplate with a recursive loop that returns the max value of a node in an xml. I also need the min value and the total count of the nodes which I can simply get from the same subtemplate. I don't wonna loop 3 times, not really good for the performance :)

Solutions I found so far:

- Create a string of the 3 values I need and get a substring of them.
- ...

I'm using xsl v1.0

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for another way of presenting multiple results, that is more convenient and natural, especially if the number of results is big.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It may not be convenient accessing each of many (say hundreds) results presented in a single string**.

**This is where the power of XML and XPath can be best seen and utilized: produce an XML tree as the result**.

Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:call-template name="sequenceStatistics">
       <xsl:with-param name="pSeq" select="*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sequenceStatistics">
  <xsl:param name="pSeq"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vCount" select="count($pSeq)"/>

  <results>
   <count><xsl:value-of select="$vCount"/></count>
    <xsl:for-each select="$pSeq">
     <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
         <min><xsl:value-of select="."/></min>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="position() = $vCount">
         <max><xsl:value-of select="."/></max>
       </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </results>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>7</num>
  <num>3</num>
  <num>9</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>4</num>
  <num>2</num>
  <num>5</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>6</num>
  <num>1</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<results>
   <count>10</count>
   <min>1</min>
   <max>10</max>
</results>
```

**Do note**:

1. **If the result is in the body of a variable, the variable type is RTF** (Result Tree Fragment) and it must be converted to a regular tree using the `xxx:node-set()` function before the nodes of the result can be accessed individually. There is no such restriction in XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0).
2. **As this example shows, there is no need of recursion to produce the maximum and minimum of a sequence** -- even in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Gonna try this and report back to you :)